# Draggable no longer working after content made dynamic

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-ui

I'm new to JQuery and I broke my draggable/droppable functionality after the content moved to an AJAX call.

When I had the HTML table with the data loaded on page load, everything worked fine. Now that I'm injecting it with AJAX, that functionality has stopped working.

Can someone please tell me what I need to do to get this working with everything being dynamic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function initDraggable(c){
   $(c).draggable();
}
$.ajax{
   ........
   success:function(){
      initDraggable($(".draggable-item"));
   }
}
```

After ajax , call init function again

Comment: Thanks. I'm a little confused. I'm not using a class for any of the rows or tds so would I instead use the table id for the `initDraggable()` function?

Comment: I was able to get this working by moving the entire draggable and droppable functions inside the AJAX success function. Am I right by doing this? It's a pretty lengthy piece of code.

Comment: @ I'm not using a class for any of the rows or tds so would I instead use the table id for the initDraggable() function?                                        --Doesn't matter, it works in both selectors